# How do I remove the white spaces around my dashboard header on reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux

How do I remove the white spaces around my dashboard header on reactjs

Anyone can help first time doing react and css. not sure what is need to make this work.

The full source code is here. 
Header.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todos, actions } = this.props
    return (
      <div style = {divStyle}>
        <h1>
            Dashboard
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

var divStyle = {
  background: "black",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "white"
}

export default Header
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as TodoActions from '../actions/todos'
import Header from '../components/Header'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todos, actions } = this.props
    return (
      <div style = {divStyle}>
        <Header/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

var divStyle = {
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0
}

App.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
var divStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your React Code. But this is an issue with CSS, you are not reseting stuff. It is caused by `margin` or `body` or something else. Use the following reset.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: var divStyle = {
  background: "black",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "white",
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
}

Comment: @phongyewtong **1.** There is an extra `,` in the end. Not sure if it is okay. **2.** Don't you have a separate CSS file? If you have one, please add it there!

Comment: var divStyle = {
  background: "black",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "white",
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0
}

Comment: @phongyewtong Can you give that style to `body` please? You need to give it to the `body`.